# Apache2.4 htaccess - negative ifModule executes regardless

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

Consider the following Apache conf directives inside `.htaccess`:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /dbug.html

<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
```

It denies access even though `mod_php5` is active, but ignores the `ErrorDocument`
If i remove the `!` it triggers the `ErrorDocument 403` - which it should, but this is backwards, and wrong ..

Any answer/advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This looks like it might be useful to block server up php pages as text when the php module is not there. Something I have been looking for...

Comment: What happens if you remove the IfModule block altogether?

Comment: @TomH - yes, it's what i'm trying to achieve, though it seems like a time-race-issue, that the module is only present - when it is, so negation will always run first on this as other modules like `mod_env`, `mod_rewrite` loads first and hits the `!mod_php` at the same time, so it yields true.

Comment: @MrWhite - if I remove this block all is well, though, it may not be well if the hosting company makes an "oops" and your entire web-application software system is exposed to the public, not just a "website" i mean.

Comment: @MrWhite - your question inspired me to think differently, thank you, it's working now and I will post an answer.

Comment: @TomH - it's working! - I'm posting the whole `.htaccess` as answer - for anyone who may be interested :D

Answer (score 1):

In some shared-hosting environments, live-module-version-switching (hot-switch) is available; as a result, the main module-name (module-handler) may be different than the target-module-name, but the target-module will show up as being present only when it is called by the module-handler.

The solution is to track down the module-handler-name and reference that instead .. contact the hosting provider. In this case, the module-handler-name is: `mod_php_null` (Hetzner); so `<ifModule !mod_php_null.c>` will work as expected -BUT- to set directives for the target-module, use the target module-name; so then `<ifModule !mod_php7.c>` will work as expected.

If there is no "module-handler" for such a module, then referring the target module directly in both conditions *should* work as it gets loaded upon server daemon startup.

As indicated in the comments, this may be (partially) beneficial to security as a portable solution between different shared -or- dedicated/managed servers; so I hope it's useful to someone:

### Improved .htaccess

```
# note :: important : read this
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# the directives expressed in this file are compatible with shared hosting and crucial to security -and framework integrity
# the objective is to provide a fast/solid/stable runtime environment that compliments the designated PHP framework
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



# conf :: main : primary config for security & compatibility
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Options           -Indexes -Multiviews
   ServerSignature   Off
   DefaultLanguage   en-US
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



# cond :: 403 : trigger `Forbidden` if missing Apache modules .. it would be better to trigger 503 instead .. (possible?)
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   <IfModule !mod_env.c>
      Require all denied
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_php_null.c>
      Require all denied
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
      Require all denied
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_headers.c>
      Require all denied
   </IfModule>
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



# defn :: vars : for DRYKIS principle .. (leave your sister out of this)
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   <IfModule mod_env.c>
      SetEnv BOTMATCH "bot|crawl|fetch|find|grab|scan|search|site|slurp|spider|wget|curl"
   </IfModule>
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



# conf :: PHP-ini : runtime - some of these may be ignored on shared-hosting .. change `mod_php7` to the available PHP module
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   <IfModule mod_php7.c>
      php_value default_charset     UTF-8
      php_value short_open_tag      On
      php_value display_errors      On
      php_value expose_php          Off
      php_value allow_url_fopen     On
      php_value memory_limit        128M
      php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
      php_value post_max_size       128M
      php_value max_input_time      30
      php_value max_execution_time  60
   </IfModule>
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



# conf :: headers : try to resolve self-signed-certificate issues and avoid version exploits .. PHP-ini "should" handle this
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header unset Server
      Header unset Strict-Transport-Security
      Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=0;includeSubDomains"
      Header always unset X-Powered-By
      Header unset X-Powered-By
   </IfModule>
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



# exec :: request : force compliance for: REST & FQDN & HTTPS/WSS .. the PHP framework handles all .. hide *debug* from "bots"
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /

      RewriteCond %{HTTP:REQUEST_METHOD} !^$
      RewriteRule ^ - [R=400,L]

      RewriteCond %{HTTP:USER_AGENT} !^$
      RewriteRule ^ - [R=400,L]

      RewriteCond %{HTTP_X_Accept} !^$
      RewriteRule ^ - [R=400,L]

      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
      RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} =http
      RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} =ws
      RewriteRule ^ wss://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

      RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/..php -f
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ..php [L]

      RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "$BOTMATCH" [NC]
      RewriteRule ^ - [R=503,L]

      RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/.auto/system/dbug.htm -f
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ .auto/system/dbug.htm [L]

      RewriteRule ^ - [R=500,L]
   </IfModule>
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The grammar in the answer above is for Apache2.4 .. For Apache 2.2 just change the syntax to something compatible, like change `Require all denied` to `deny from all` .. - hope it helps.

Comment: Note that the check on `<ifModule !mod_php_null.c>` and then later `<ifModule mod_php5.c>` is intensional.